# Case sensitive javascript filename in a source tag in Linux containers for .NetCore apps

Tags: javascript, docker, .net-core, docker-container

I am observing an odd behavior while containerizing a .NetCore app. On the server side, there is a file in "wwwroot/js" folder named "myScript.js" - notice a lower case 'm'. On my development laptop, the containerized .NetCore app with a "<script src="~/js/MyScript.js>" line in an html file causes a runtime error in the browser console showing a 404 error, "myScript.js" not found. On another developer's computer, when using the same source code, with an identical dockerfile with the same base container 'mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0'  and everything else appearing identical in the Visual Studio settings, the same containerized app, deployed and running via Visual Studio 2022 Docker interface, just like on my laptop,  runs fine. There is no 404 error and the application works fine. This only happens when containerizing to a Linux rather than a Windows container, which can make sense since Linix is case sensitive, while Windows OS is not. So, I must assume there is a config setting somewhere which forces case sensitivity on or off when server side code fetches the .js file. Can anyone direct me where/what that setting is? Or is there another cause?

As a background, the app is web app built with a .NetCore 6, but same issue exists with built on .NetCore 3.1. Our Windows Docker Desktop version is the only thing that appears different - I have 3.2.2, while the other developer has 4.6.1, but I wouldn't think this could make a runtime difference?

Comment: You're using the same base tag, `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0`, but that's only part of it. Are you both targeting Linux containers? The 6.0 tag is multi-arch/multi-platform so it will get a Linux or Windows container based on the host configuration.

Comment: We both target Linux, both of us have Docker Windows Desktop set to use Linux containers rather than Windows.

Comment: I have found this posting on apspnetcore github https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/18640 which seems to confirm that the filename will/should be case sensitive when deployed in a Linux conainer, but still doesn't explain why it works on one of the deelopers' computer.